Error Installing Python Dependencies for ESP8266_RTOS_SDK
Originally, I wanted to use PlatformIO for programming the ESP8266 (ESP-12F module) to make my life easier. Unfortunately, I found out that the Espressif 8266 platfor has a vary old version of the ESP8266 RTOS SDK. The latest version of the SDK is v3.4, and it is significantly different, including potentially existing external libraries.
I followed the guide on the SDK website here, but when installing the Python dependencies, I encountered an error that I haven't been able to resolve yet.
Fo example when I what to start menuconfig (make menuconfig) of hello_word example I get an error
The following Python requirements are not satisfied:
pyelftools>=0.22

The error will show, when I try tu run python -m pip install --user -r $IDF_PATH/requirements.txt:
Using cached pyelftools-0.31.tar.gz (14.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: C:/msys32_espressif/mingw32/bin/python.exe C:/msys32_espressif/mingw32/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix c:/users/asus/appdata/local/temp/pip-build-env-zjp9dh/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools >= 46.4.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (3 lines):

...

ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=46.4.0

Also I get the warning (but I don't think that this couse the problem with installing dependencies.
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

I am now in dead end, what do you think, please?
I have tried installing dependencies manually but I get some other errors.
EDIT1:
Add the --no-build-isolation solved this issue solved the problem:
python -m pip install --no-build-isolation --user -r $IDF_PATH/requirements.txt

Originally by: https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/issues/1271
EDIT2:
After successfull installing the dependencies, I was able to run menuconfig, but I discovered that the toolchain was missing or the path was not correct. So, I searched for a solution and resolved this error as follows:
The original error was:
make: xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc:
Command not found expr: syntax error: undefined argument „5.2.0“

Solution (https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/issues/785):

download toolchain from https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp8266-rtos-sdk/en/latest/get-started/windows-setup.html

extract the folder int PATH:/esp

in PATH:/etc/profile.d create file with the name export_toolchain_path.sh with the code inside:


export PATH=$PATH:/esp/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin

After restarting mingw32 console, this script will run. When you run printenv PATH, the toolchain path should be there.
The fact that the environment didm't work for me right away, despite following the guide, could have been due to many reasons, but this was the solution that worked for me.
